# how to develop a function finding sum of customers in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a function to find the total number of customers? User will enter a product name based upon the name and it should return the number of customers for that product. I use `adventureworks` database.

Comment: You want a function and not a stored procedure?

Comment: show Your table structure

Comment: Post the table structure.

Comment: SELECT P.EnglishProductName,count(C.FirstName) As NoOfCustomers FROM Dimproduct As P inner join FactInternetSales AS F on P.ProductKey=F.ProductKey inner join DimCustomer as C on C.CustomerKey=F.CustomerKey group by P.EnglishProductName –   This is the query to find no of customers for product.so how coulid i use it in functions for each input product given by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function based on your query in command.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetCustomerCount(@ProductKey AS INT)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT P.EnglishProductName, count(C.FirstName) AS NoOfCustomers 
            FROM Dimproduct AS P 
                INNER JOIN FactInternetSales AS F ON P.ProductKey = F.ProductKey 
                INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS C ON C.CustomerKey = F.CustomerKey
                WHERE P.ProductKey = @ProductKey
            GROUP BY P.EnglishProductName)
END
```

Creating function in sql is simple. Try to learn on your own.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191320.aspx

Comment: actualy m beginner to pl sql so finding it bit dificult.thanks anyways

Comment: SELECT P.EnglishProductName,count(C.FirstName) As NoOfCustomers FROM Dimproduct As P
inner join FactInternetSales AS F on P.ProductKey=F.ProductKey
inner join DimCustomer as C on C.CustomerKey=F.CustomerKey 
group by P.EnglishProductName

Comment: This is the query to find no of customers for product.so how coulid i use it in functions for each input product given by user

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(CustomerID), ProductID from Sales
```

This assumes there is a customer ID and a Product ID in a related table, sales for example